# Warning: Illegal string offset 'username' in

Tags: php

I am making a user login form for my website and this error pops up [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIkbI.png) my code is:

```
<?php if( isset($user) ): ?>

    <br />Welcome <?= $user['username']; ?>
    <br /><br />You are successfully logged in!
    <br /><br />
    <a href="logout.php">Logout?</a>

<?php else: ?>

<h1>Please Login or Regester</h1>
<a href="login.php">Login</a> or
<a href="register.php">Register</a>

<?php endif; ?>
```

can someone help me if I need to provide anymore code i will do so to fix this error

Comment: what is the output of print_r($user). Only if it is an array.

Comment: instead of if( isset($user)   use if( isset($user['username'])

Comment: May be `$user['username']` is not a string. Please print $user and check what it displays.

Comment: The error means that `$user` is a string, not an array. Why are you trying to index it.

Comment: There are a dozen similar questions in the **Related** list. Did you do any searching before posting the question?

Comment: Show how you're setting `$user` farther up.

Comment: @Vegeta your solution fixed the website btw this is what im making http://SouthDakotaGames14.ddns.net

Comment: @Barmar: my mistake thank you..

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
<?php if(isset($user['username'])){echo $user['username'];} else{ echo 'Guest';} ?>
```

Comment: working somewhat but i need to edit the code a little bit to get the else that i want. I added the peripherals of the code to get more useful responces

Answer (score 0):

@Vegeta fixed my problem with:

instead of if( isset($user) use if( isset($user['username'])

website works now